# Selenium lagging when opening more sessions

Tags: python, selenium, web, selenium-webdriver, driver

I am using VPS with 8 CPU cores.

Problem started when I opened around 30 sessions of Chrome web driver. I minimized all browsers to reduce CPU usage and I was tracking tests inside my prompt. 
Usually 1 test lasts 55 seconds, but when I have more sessions they vary from 1 minute to 3 minutes sometimes. What is cause of the problem here? My CPU usage is around 20 percent of all time.

Comment: Have you tried adding `chrome_options`? you can use `'--headless'` like this `chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')`

Comment: I did, tests work great then but the problem is CPU usage. I can't handle more then 5 headless chromes and my VPS is pretty strong.

Comment: Do all the 30 sessions need to run in parallel?

Comment: Yes they do. It is crucial for me that tests run in period of 55 seconds - 1 minute max.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the problem most probably is RAM usage. For browser execution RAM is crucial and when you got to the limit, the tests start to perform slower. Check out the usage of RAM and most likely you will see that 30 instances of a browser use it all.

As a suggestion play around the number of browsers and try to keep an optimal percentage of RAM usage. In your case maybe limiting the number of parallel threads to 25 or even 20 will make entire suite run faster than in 30. But of course, if there is an option it's better to just add more memory and proceed with fast automation ;)

[some more details about FF and Chrome RAM usage](https://www.businessinsider.com/google-chrome-vs-firefox-performance-memory-2018-7)

*Edit after a comment that Ram is only used by 15%*

It could simply be an app, that slows down under load. Yep, 30 threads do not look anyhow valuable but it may depend on the app-environment hardware or just that some part of an app's performance has an issue. We had a case when our tests were working fine on one environment in 200 threads, but when data center was migrating, we switched to different environments (that were configured differently) and we found that at the beginning the new environment only could normally work under 30-50 threads (comparing to usual 200). We reported it as an issue and it was confirmed and solved by IT team.

As a suggestion for this case - try to monitor when does the slowdown happen, is there any patterns for example - 'after 10 minutes of test suite run' or 'after some action on the app being called'. This info may help to investigate the potential problem on an app side.

Comment: I have 40gb of ram, and when i run tests, only 15% is used.

Comment: @MarkLetterman updated my answer with a second suggestion as the RAM does not seem to be the case

Comment: I noticed what is the problem that is causing lag. It is .sendkeys() command when i try to write something by finding element. This function is very slow on Chrome when is minimized. I wonder how can i speed it up?

Comment: @MarkLetterman the only thing I can think of is replacing sendKeys method call with javascript. it should look something like WebElement el = ........;   ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].value='text you want to enter'", el)